# Sonar cloud does not reflect the code coverage information for maven project with Azure CICD pipeline

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, sonarcloud

I have a Spring boot application. I am using the Azure CICD pipeline for delivery. I am using the sonar cloud for code quality analysis and configured it in the pipeline as a step. When the pipeline runs the sonar cloud dashboard gets updated with the vulnerabilities, code smells, etc... But the code coverage is always shown as 0%. There are a lot of tests in my application and not sure why it is not reflecting in the sonar cloud.
My pipeline looks like this (major steps):

```
steps:
  - install java step here

  - configure maven step here

  - task: SonarCloudPrepare@1
    inputs:
      SonarCloud: 'My Sonarcloud connection'
      organization: 'myOrganization'
      scannerMode: 'Other'
      extraProperties: |
        sonar.projectKey=myOrganization_JavaApp---API
        sonar.projectName=JavaApp - API

  - task: Maven@3
    displayName: 'Build Maven Artifacts'
    inputs:
      mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
      goals: 'package -Dactive.profile=$(active_profile)'
      publishJUnitResults: true
      testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
      codeCoverageToolOption: 'JaCoCo'
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
      mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
      mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
      effectivePomSkip: false
      sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
      sqMavenPluginVersionChoice: 'latest'

  - task: SonarCloudPublish@1
    inputs:
      pollingTimeoutSec: '300'

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy Artifacts to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
      Contents: '**/target/**/*.war'
      TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    condition: succeededOrFailed()

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact to: drop'
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Once the pipeline runs, it shows all the code coverage details in CICD job.
[image]
However, the coverage is not reflected in the sonar cloud. It is always 0%
I would like to know two things

1. what is wrong with my pipeline configuration?
2. Is there any changes/config I need to add to the `pom.xml` to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing from my side, adding `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=<path-to-xml-report>` in SonarCloudPrepare@1 task can resolve the issue.

My SonarCloudPrepare@1 task:

```
- task: SonarCloudPrepare@1
  displayName: 'Prepare analysis configuration'
  inputs:
    SonarCloud: 'SonarCloudSC'
    organization: '***sonarcloudorg'
    scannerMode: 'Other'
    extraProperties: |
      sonar.projectKey=***
      sonar.projectName=***
      sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths= CCReport43F6D5EF/jacoco.xml
```

Then I can see the code coverage in Sonar Cloud:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where do you get this path CCReport43F6D5EF/jacoco.xml? Doesn't it change this (CCReport43F6D5EF) string for each build? If so how to set this dynamic value?

Comment: Thank you for the support. This worked. Ignore my earlier comment. The `CCReport43F6D5EF` is always the same and when publishing the artifact it is renamed to a different name. But we can always access the `jacoco.xml` vi the `CCReport43F6D5EF/jacoco.xml` path.